# Globally save results inside a function over many iterations

Tags: r, function, xgboost

I am working with the following code, taken from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/silverstone1903/xgboost-grid-search-r)

I am trying to save the results of the `evaluation_log` for all `nfold = 2`

This is the line I am trying to modify;

```
xvalidationScores <- as.data.frame(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log)
```

I can globally save the results by using the following;

```
xvalidationScores <<- as.data.frame(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log)
```

however this just saves the last `nfold` result. But I am looking to save all the folds to evaluate the training/test error.

I have tried a `for loop` without success.

```
for(i in 1:2){
xvalidationScores[[i]] <<- as.data.frame(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log)
}
```

Code:

```
searchGridSubCol <- expand.grid(subsample = c(0.5, 0.6), 
                                colsample_bytree = c(0.5, 0.6),
                                max_depth = c(3, 4),
                                min_child = seq(1), 
                                eta = c(0.01)
)

ntrees <- 5

system.time(
rmseErrorsHyperparameters <- apply(searchGridSubCol, 1, function(parameterList){

  #Extract Parameters to test
  currentSubsampleRate <- parameterList[["subsample"]]
  currentColsampleRate <- parameterList[["colsample_bytree"]]
  currentDepth <- parameterList[["max_depth"]]
  currentEta <- parameterList[["eta"]]
  currentMinChild <- parameterList[["min_child"]]
  xgboostModelCV <- xgb.cv(data =  dtrain, nrounds = ntrees, nfold = 2, showsd = TRUE, 
                       metrics = "rmse", verbose = TRUE, "eval_metric" = "rmse",
                     "objective" = "reg:linear", "max.depth" = currentDepth, "eta" = currentEta,                               
                     "subsample" = currentSubsampleRate, "colsample_bytree" = currentColsampleRate
                      , print_every_n = 10, "min_child_weight" = currentMinChild, booster = "gbtree",
                     early_stopping_rounds = 10)

  xvalidationScores <- as.data.frame(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log)
  rmse <- tail(xvalidationScores$test_rmse_mean, 1)
  trmse <- tail(xvalidationScores$train_rmse_mean,1)
  output <- return(c(rmse, trmse, currentSubsampleRate, currentColsampleRate, currentDepth, currentEta, currentMinChild))

}))
```

EDIT:

This is the original structure (without the `xvalidationScores` stored in `output`. Which is a matrix.

```
          V1         V2         V3        V4         V5         V6
1: 0.9537040  0.9750880  0.9856087 0.9696030  0.9860550  0.9936100
2: 0.9023817  0.9007057  0.8997263 0.9046303  0.9051127  0.9041987
3: 0.6000000  0.6000000  0.6000000 0.6000000  0.6000000  0.6000000
4: 1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000 1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
5: 8.0000000 10.0000000 12.0000000 8.0000000 10.0000000 12.0000000
6: 0.0100000  0.0100000  0.0100000 0.0500000  0.0500000  0.0500000
7: 1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000 1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
```

When I include the `xvalidationScore` the `rmseErrorHyperparameters` turns out to be a list.

Comment: why don't you add `xvalidationScores` in the output list?

Comment: `output` gets stored in `rmseErrorsHyperparameters`. Therefore, you could change the last line to `output <- list(xvalidationScores, c(rmse, trmse, currentSubsampleRate, currentColsampleRate, currentDepth, currentEta, currentMinChild))`.

Comment: Thanks! both options work great, I can now access the data in a list

Comment: I have run into a problem with this method however. I was able to get it working as you suggested but saving the results of the evaluation_log changed the structure of the data.frame and the further code on the github page does not work. (I edit the original post to show the structure).

Comment: Forget the above comment, actually having the data in a list is great!